# Adding an image page banner to shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WordPress 4.9.6.

I have set the shop page to be the home-page.

How do I add a page banner to the shop page. I would like to add it just above the breadcrumb trail.

I have tried adding this to the following page archive-product.php

```
if (is_shop()) {
        $args = array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat');
        $product_categories = get_categories( $args  );
        $term_id = $product_categories[0]->term_id;  
        $content = get_term_meta($term_id, 'cat_meta');
        if(isset($content[0]['cat_header'])){
            echo do_shortcode($content[0]['cat_header']);
        }
}
```

Unfortunately, not able to add any image to the page.

Comment: Do you want to displayed any category image? Or do you want one fixed image for shop page?

Comment: use hooks, stop editing theme files!

Comment: @dipmala i want a fixed static image banner in place of the breadcrumb section in the home page.

Comment: Tobias, explain?

Comment: @dipmala: can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve using 2 methods.

1) Add your static image directly at the beginning of **archive-product.php** 
 `echo "<img src='{YOUR_IMAGE_PATH}'>";`

2) Add filter in your theme's functions.php file.

```
 add_action ('woocommerce_archive_description' , 'shop_banner',99);
 function shop_banner() {
   echo  '<img src="{YOUR_IMAGE_PATH}" >';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure if I understand exactly what you want. But this is what I understand so far.

If you want to **display an Static image banner above the breadcrumbs in your Shop Page**. 
You could use the `woocommerce_before_main_content` action.

```
function BannerShop(){

  if(is_shop()){
    echo '<img src="https://localhost/demosite/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/512x356.png" >';
  }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'BannerShop', 10 );
```

Here i show the before and after. BTW I don't know what *theme* are you using so it may be displayed different.

Before 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv2YK.jpg

After https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTfCa.jpg